# Netbeans 8.1 Amazon Beanstalk plugin

Tags: netbeans-8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I get this message when i click in cloud service in NetBeans 8.1.

**No cloud plugins are installed in the IDE**

The IDE needs a cloud plugin (e.g. Amazon Beanstalk plugin) to enable registering and using a cloud. Use Plugins Manager to install server plugins.

But when i open plugins i cant find Amazon Beanstalk plugin.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the plugin is not more (unfortunely) on netbeans. The Amazon Beanstalk plugin was present on NB versions prior to 8.0 so now is not present on plugin list.

**UPDATE**
You must install java web and ee plugin in order to use Amazon Beanstalk plugin.